# how to connect to remote registry with Python 3.x winreg

Tags: python, windows, dns, registry, winreg

I'm facing a problem when trying to connect to a remote machine's registry through **python winreg**.
I'm trying to catch mapped network printer from the currently logged on user from registry.

My code is as followed:

```
def enumRegKeySubkeys():
    key_path = "Printers\\Connections"
    target = r"\\192.168.20.164"
    rem_reg = ConnectRegistry(target, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    rem_key = OpenKey(rem_reg, key_path, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
    result = []
    index = 0
    while True:
        try:
            subkey = EnumKey(rem_key, index)
            result.append(subkey)
            index += 1
        except EnvironmentError:
    return result
```

When I'm running this I'm getting error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last)
>   File ".\test2.py", line 21, in 
>   print(enumRegKeySubkeys())
>   File ".\test2.py", line 8, in enumRegKeySubkeys
>   rem_key = OpenKey(rem_reg, key_path, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
>   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

If I'm running it locally

```
rem_reg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
```

then there is no problem and I get what i want.

It all takes place in a Windows domain environment, is running with administrative (domain) rights, and the remote registry service on the client is running.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You're logging into the system using your own credentials, so `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` will be mapped to "\Registry\User\<SID OF YOUR ACCOUNT>". If there's no loaded profile for your account, it defaults to the ".DEFAULT" profile, which doesn't  have the subkey path "Printers\Connections".  You could open the `HKEY_USERS` predefined handle instead if you know the account's SID subkey.

Answer (score -1):

In fact,`ConnectRegistry(target, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)` is equal to dos command `reg query \\target\HKEY_CURRENT_USER`,which is not effective,because reg query for remote server only can be avaible for  `HKLM` and `HKU`

Type `reg query /?` in dos window,you can see this:

`[\\Machine\]FullKey:  Machine - Name of remote machine, omitting defaults to the current machine. Only HKLM(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) and HKU(HKEY_USERS) are available on remote machines`